# There is a bug in the Stack Overflow user settings

Tags: bug, developer-story

Just recently I was trying to update my user account developer story. If I add a new item, then it is not showing the gear (edit and delete options). I added a picture to easy understand.

[image]

Is this a bug from Stack Overflow or not?

Comment: @GinoMempin This question is some kind of update of your question. the problem gear hiding is hide on both update and add new portion.